access fields outside group in Sumo query
During testing process I'm trying to analyze logs from Sumo Logic.
Each product have status, and the status can change multiple times during the process. I want to create a query to get the last status for each product:
("Deletion product findings")
| parse "productId=*," as productId
| parse "findings=*," as findings
| parse "status=*." as status
| values (status) as status by productId, findings
| where status = "FAILED"

The last log entry for each product contains the most update status, but after the grouping using values function I'm losing the timestamp field.
How can I get for each product the last entry?
There is an option to access fields that not include in the values statement (after the statement)?
